# Module source string.replace causes garbled bundle

Tags: webpack

If I change the length of a module's source by means of a string.replace():

```js
compiler.hooks.shouldEmit.tap('WebpackSvgSpritely', compilation => {
  Object.keys(compilation.modules).map((i) => {
    const source = compilation.modules[i]._source;
    if (source) {
      const value = source._value;
      value = value.replace('iconset-[hash].svg', 'iconset-1234567890.svg');
    }
  });

  return true;
});
```

My bundle output becomes garbled with a harmony export being inject incorrectly directly in the middle of my code:

```js
// Incorrect
var Icon = function Icon() {
  xhr.open('GET', 'img/iconset-1234567890.svg', true);
  xhr.s/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["a"] = (init););
};

export default Icon;
```

While without a string replacement (aka no change to source length) no error.

```js
// Correct
var Icon = function Icon() {
  var init = function init() {
    xhr.open('GET', 'img/iconset-[hash].svg', true);
    xhr.send();
  };

  init();
};
/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["a"] = (Icon);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a able to fix this by using:

```js
let source = compilation.modules[i].source();

// instead of

let source = compilation.modules[i]._source._value;
```

---

Getting / Putting manipulated source back into the build is as simple as:

```js
let source = compilation.modules[i].source();

/// ... do things to source ... ///

compilation.modules[i].source = () => source;
```

---

This works for assests too, however you need to change the size prop as well:

```js
let source = compilation.modules[i].source();

/// ... do things to source ... ///

compilation.assets[i] = {
  source: function () {
    return source;
  },
  size: function () {
    return source.length;
  }
};
```